# Flutter how to parse JSON Mongodb data

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to parse some JSON data with mongodb. I have no data found I think that the problem is with the difference in field in mongodb data

```
{"imei":"865566048694354","_id":"5e7c996fd6eb5f039c50bd26","createdAt":"2020-03-26T12:00:47.021Z","updatedAt":"2020-03-26T12:00:47.021Z","__v":0},{"imei":{"test":{"tactileState":"ignore","pixelState":"ignore"},"name":"h12hhhhgkhh"},"_id":"5ea8357d8c562b3dd8fe5bf1","createdAt":"2020-04-28T13:54:05.094Z","updatedAt":"2020-04-28T13:54:05.094Z","__v":0},{"imei":{"test":{"tactileState":"ignore","pixelState":"ignore"},"name":"h12hhhhgkhh"},"_id":"5ea8366741a5e527446744a2","createdAt":"2020-04-28T13:57:59.035Z","updatedAt":"2020-04-28T13:57:59.035Z","__v":0},{"imei":{"test":{"tactileState":"ignore","pixelState":"ignore","greyState":"ignore"},"name":"h12hhhhgkhh"},"_id":"5ea837614cf7ed30f0163c38","createdAt":"2020-04-28T14:02:09.395Z","updatedAt":"2020-04-28T14:02:09.395Z","__v":0},{"imei":{"test":{"bafleState":"1","microState":"1","vibreurState":"1"},"name":"h12hhhhgkhh"},"_id":"5ea837854cf7ed30f0163c39","createdAt":"2020-04-28T14:02:45.287Z","updatedAt":"2020-04-28T14:02:45.287Z","__v":0}
```

If you can help me how to write the class and how to write the method in flutter because everything which I made always snapshot has no data I think that the problem in the difference in fields in mongodb data makes the problem because all tutorial and article which I see didn't use different database field always the same structure even with embedded document.

Comment: from where dou you get this json? directly from mongoDB? or from a server? can you then configure the server to parse `ObjectID`s and `ISODates`s?

Comment: this json is from robot 3T

Comment: so you copied it? normally a json would not have such values as `ObjectID` or `ISODate`. does robot 3T has a feature to export the final JSON?

Comment: yes and i do all the works you can find detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613180/flutter-parsing-json-data-no-data?noredirect=1#comment108990052_61613180

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a json like this

```
{
 "name": "John Smith",
 "email": "john@example.com"
}
```

With `dart:convert, you can serialize this JSON model in two ways.

```
Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(jsonString);
print('Howdy, ${user['name']}!');
```

Or create a model like this

```
class User {
final String name;
final String email;

User(this.name, this.email);

User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : name = json['name'],
    email = json['email'];

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
{
  'name': name,
  'email': email,
};
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Map userMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
var user = User.fromJson(userMap);

print('Howdy, ${user.name}!');
```

Reference is [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).

Comment: one more question it makes a difference if model a time like this {name : mohamed email: mohamed@gmail.com} and one more time {name : ali  age:20}

Comment: You can use Date.. or simply use String. Then wherever needed you can convert the string to a Date Object.

Comment: please can you help me writing a mthode of get because i always have the same errors

Comment: can you tell me what is the response from the API? how is the date translated in the API?

Comment: i modififed the question to the response.body check it